# How to force the base template to be used for a block?

Tags: template, frontend

I'm currently developing a Module and I'm having a problem where if I put my layout in the base template folder instead of the current design template folder, the layout doesn't get loaded/found. I hope someone could enlighten me on how I can configure this properly, since I can't really find it when searching on Google..

This is my (layout).xml for the block/Module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.8.0">
    <default>
        <shopcommerce_slider_front_index_index>
            <reference>
                <block type="shopcommerce_slider_front/slider" name="sc_slider" template="shopcommerce/slider/layout.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </shopcommerce_slider_front_index_index>
    </default>
</layout>
```

frontend section of config.xml:

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <shopcommerce_slider>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>ShopCommerce_Slider</module>
                    <frontName>scslider</frontName>
                </args>
            </shopcommerce_slider>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <shopcommerce_slider>
                    <file>shopcommerce.xml</file>
                </shopcommerce_slider>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

blocks section of the config.xml:

```
<blocks>
    <shopcommerce_slider_adminhtml>
        <class>ShopCommerce_Slider_Block_Adminhtml</class>
    </shopcommerce_slider_adminhtml>
    <shopcommerce_slider_front>
        <class>ShopCommerce_Slider_Block</class>
    </shopcommerce_slider_front>
</blocks>
```

If any more code/information is needed I'm happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento, *there are no process/code exits which apply base template whenever  current theme template exits.*

I guss that your issue in handle.it may be

**shopcommerce_slider_index_index** instead of `shopcommerce_slider_front_index_index`

Also https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/83878/4564 all the point is valid.You need to check

Comment: If the controller is `ShopCommerce_Slider_Front_IndexController`, the handle is correct (should use the router name, not the front name).

Comment: Yes..i have done a mistake thanks for update..... for ShopCommerce_Slider_Front_IndexController  shopcommerce_slider_front_index_index is true

Comment: The controller namespace is indeed ShopCommerce_Slider_Front_IndexController, and it's called correctly. Though you HAVE found the cause of why the base template isn't loaded, which was because of an old XML in the other design folder.. So thank you for that! (I've been so busy checking all my existing files that I skipped the most obvious one ..)

Answer (score 2):

I think you jumped to the wrong conclusions. Your layout XML is probably loaded, but it is invalid:

1. ```
   <default>
       <shopcommerce_slider_front_index_index>
   ```

   You cannot nest layout handles like this. It should be either just `<default>` for all pages, or just `<shopcommerce_slider_front_index_index>` for this particular controller action.
2. ```
   <reference>
   ```

   A reference element always needs a `name` attribute, otherwise it does not know *what* to reference. For example, to add your block in the content area:

   ```
   <reference name="content">
   ```

Comment: Aah I see, that's why my layout kept loading twice all the time.. Thank you for the knowledge :)